# map doesn't return correct array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Tried to do a map to set a value of selected to true and false but it doesn't change existing true value away, what's wrong?

```
selectTab = tab => e => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    this.setState(
      {
        data: data.map(o =>
          o.tab === tab ? { selected: true, ...o } : { selected: false, ...o }
        )
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.data)
    );
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/885l8q537l

Answer (score 2):

Try and spread the object first, and then add the `selected` property. Otherwise the `selected` property in `o` will overwrite it every time.

```
selectTab = tab => e => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      data: prevState.data.map(o =>
        o.tab === tab ? { ...o, selected: true } : { ...o, selected: false }
      )
    }),
    () => console.log(this.state.data)
  );
};
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        tab: 1,
        content: "Tab 1 content",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        tab: 2,
        content: "Tab 2 content"
      },
      {
        tab: 3,
        content: "Tab 3 content"
      }
    ]
  };

  selectTab = tab => e => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        data: prevState.data.map(o =>
          o.tab === tab ? { ...o, selected: true } : { ...o, selected: false }
        )
      }),
      () => console.log(this.state.data)
    );
  };
  
  render() {
    const { activeTab, data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(obj => (
          <div onClick={this.selectTab(obj.tab)}>{obj.tab}</div>
        ))}
        {data.map(obj => (
          <div>{obj.selected && obj.content}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: wow nice catch, is there any case you would want to use spread at the end?

Comment: @DennisNgu: For object spread I can't think of any use-case, but if for array then yes `const newArr = [...oldArr, newElement]` vs `const newArr = [newElement, ...oldArr]`. It will change the ordering of element

Comment: @DennisNgu You most often want to create a new object with some property overriden, i.e. `{ ...o, selected: true}`, but you might e.g. have an object with default values and potentially override them by putting the object at the end like `const settings = { logLevel: 2, ...o };`

Comment: @Tholle: Ha! I never thought it could be using it for default value! Brilliant thanks!